# Perform operation right after showing an activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I'd like to start an animation right after an activity is created. The problem is that I have to call the method once everything is showed on the screen, let's say one second after being showed for the first time.

In other words, I'm looking for a method to be executed right after onCreate() but after the activity is shown:

[image: Activity lifecicle]

Thanks!

Comment: That's a pretty picture! What's wrong with starting it at the end of `onCreate()` or `onResume()` after you set your `Views`? You can put it in your own method at the end of either method and have your animation in that method

Comment: It's not working that way because I need the GUI to be drawn before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assume that the GUI has been drawn in onCreate().   In fact it often is not.

The best way to catch when everything has finally be rendered on screen is with:

```
 @Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) { ... }
```

Put your thing in a timer here.

Comment: It works fine that way! I think this method it's going to be executed not only when the activity is created, so I've set a boolean to start the animation just once

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you set up your `layout` in `onCreate()` it looks like you can use [setStartTime(long millis)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setStartTime%28long%29) on your animation object.

```
public void onCreate(...)
{
    super.onCreate(...);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    //  do whatever else you need to
    // create your animation
    animation.setStartTime(1000); // should start it in one second
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start your animation in [onPostResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPostResume%28%29), which is invoked after onResume() finished.